# SlidingMenu and Android-PullToRefresh libraries conflict

Tags: android, libraries, conflicting-libraries

I am currently using 2 libraries in my Android project:

- SlidingMenu: https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu
- Android-PullToRefresh: https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh

With Android 4.x everything works right, but in Android 2.x I get a StackOverflow Exception.

I am not sure if it is an Android version issue or a hardware issue.

This is the log of the exception:

```
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179): java.lang.StackOverflowError
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.text.Styled.measureText(Styled.java:430)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.text.Layout.measureText(Layout.java:1655)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.text.Layout.getLineMax(Layout.java:689)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.text.Layout.draw(Layout.java:340)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.text.BoringLayout.draw(BoringLayout.java:365)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.widget.TextView.onDraw(TextView.java:4259)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6880)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.widget.AbsListView.dispatchDraw(AbsListView.java:1492)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.widget.ListView.dispatchDraw(ListView.java:3138)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6986)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.widget.AbsListView.draw(AbsListView.java:2600)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView$InternalListView.draw(PullToRefreshListView.java:281)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.view.View.buildDrawingCache(View.java:6642)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.view.ViewGroup.onAnimationStart(ViewGroup.java:1259)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1505)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.draw(ViewPager.java:1574)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at com.slidingmenu.lib.CustomViewAbove.dispatchDraw(CustomViewAbove.java:830)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
05-22 13:34:30.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15179):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
```

Can somebody help me to solve the issue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You generally see this error when you have too many nested views - a problem which is exacerbated on older versions of Android.

However, I have also noticed that the slidingmenu lib can cause this on older versions of android (3.X or earlier). I used to see this error all the time and it was originating from the slidingmenu code - my own views were only nested 10-15 deep (not great, but not disastrous). I switched to the menu-drawer library https://github.com/SimonVT/android-menudrawer and the error disappeared.

Things to try...

1. Fire up the android device monitor or hierarchy viewer (http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-ui.html) and have a look at your layouts. If there are any views deeper than say, 15-20 you might want to have a look at optimizing your layouts.
2. Try swapping out your sliding-menu lib for either google's own (in the support lib) or the one I mentioned above (which may be easier to swap as it follows a similar design to slidingmenu - it took me about an hour).

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you @Neil.
I used hierarchy viewer and I removed two or three hierarchy levels, what solved the problem (I changed nested LinearLayouts by a single RelativeLayout for instance).
Anyway, both libraries add "extra" levels in the hierarchy, so this is a point to have in consideration.

Comment: Thank you for the tip! I had exactly the same problem, i remodel my views, removing one or two LinearLayout and works! The main problem was the LinearLayouts, Thanks a lot again, you save my day